# is it possible to run simple python games on android os

Tags: android, python

I started learning programming recently using python and have always had a keen interest in the android os and hope to do more with it when I get more experienced.

I have SL4A and python installed on my tablet.  I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out how run simple games written in python on my tablet.

For instance, I made a simple hangman game as an assignment: is it possible to run that on my tablet, and if so what do I need to do?

I have seen a lot of python and android related stuff online but I find it hard to get a simple example about how exactly to use python with android.  Furthermore, what exactly are the limitations/best uses for python in relation to android devices?  Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know of Kivi (http://kivy.org/). Going this route may help you.

Comment: I have Kivy installed on Ubuntu but again I would just like to see a simple example of how it all works together. I am finding it hard to get my head around it.

Comment: well, I too have not used it so far, so can't comment on this. I guess, you have already tries Jpype or Jython etc.